# How to fill a row listview according to another listview inside it

Tags: android, listview, size, height

I have a ListView that each row has a photo and under the photo there is another ListView with comments about the photo. The problem is that the child ListView shows only the first row because the size of the parent ListView.

Is there any way to make the parent ListView size flexibility according to child ListView size?

Comment: I don't think we could implement 2 listviews in a single activity? 
Though,I am not sure..i don't think we could set Heights for 2 listviews in single activity.

Comment: post some code........

Answer (score 0):

My xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relLayoutMain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@layout/background" 
    >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/photoList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
        android:paddingTop="5sp" >

    </ListView>     
</RelativeLayout>
```

The row layout for the photoList is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imgView"
       android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:paddingLeft="10dp"
       android:paddingRight="10dp"
       android:layout_below="@+id/llUserHeader"
       android:adjustViewBounds="true"
       />


    <ListView android:id="@+id/commentList"

        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgView"   
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
        >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the row layout for commentList is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:paddingLeft="10sp"
   android:paddingRight="10sp"
   android:paddingTop="5sp"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   >
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/usernamecomment"
            android:text="@string/share_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
             />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/comment"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3sp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```